# What are the differences and connections between UML Profile diagram & UML Class diagrams

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am doing research for developing a software platform and I have created some class diagrams for the platform. My supervisor adviced me to use UML profiles as well to describe the platform in a more detailed way. However, after googling i still do not really get the difference between the Class diagrams and UML profiling. At the moment I do not think you can connect them. Can anybody help me with my question?

Comment: This may help:https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-profile-diagram/

Comment: https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/uml-diagram-types-examples/: may help you.

Answer (score 1):

UML profiles are an extension mechanism of UML and they can be used to define new stereotypes, tagged values and constraints. These stereotypes etc., can then be used in your class diagram when, for example, classes share certain characteristics.

For example, you could define a profile for Enterprise Java Beans that contains the definition for a class stereotype for a Bean.
If you then annotate a class in your class diagram with the stereotype `<<Bean>>`, then readers and tools that know about the profile will also know what it means for a class to have the stereotype `<<Bean>>` and they can validate your diagram against the enhanced definitions.